# System.map file update

Tags: linux, kernel

I found that System.map file contains addresses of symbols. Does it involve system calls? I read that it is only updated when a new kernel is newly compiled.

So does that means that except for a new kernel compilation, these are always stored in the same address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`System.map`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System.map) contains a [symbol table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_table), i.e. a list of function names in the Linux kernel, with for each function the address at which its code is loaded in memory (the addresses are not physical addresses, they're in the kernel's address space, like any executable symbol table is in the loaded process address space). This isn't limited to system calls (the interfaces exposed to user processes): the file also lists functions that might be called by a loaded module, and even internal functions. The system calls are the symbols whose name begins with `sys_`.

The addresses are associated to a particular kernel binary (`vmlinux`, `bzImage` or other format; the image format doesn't change the addresses, it's just an encoding); they are reproducible for a given kernel source, configuration and compiler. The file is generated by [`scripts/mksysmap`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.37/scripts/mksysmap) near the end of the kernel build process; it is the output of the [`nm`](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.21/binutils/nm.html) command.

The file is used mainly for debugging, but it's also read when compiling some third-party modules that use unstable kernel interfaces (unstable as in changing from one version to the next).

Comment: What does the address there meant actually?

Comment: `ps` and `klogd` do use `System.map` (but not necessarily).

Comment: @wag: It looks like `ps` used to need `System.map`, but no longer does with kernels ≥2.6.

Comment: ok, then it's like `lsof` which used to consult `System.map` too.